# Chrome browser history: is it possible to see sent emails from Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, history

I sent an email from my Gmail account. However, something went wrong, and I cannot see it in my "Sent" folder.

Is it possible to use Chrome, to see POST request I have sent, to inspect the problem?
Is it possible to show body (text) of my sent email using Chrome history or some other Chrome tools?

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the email was delivered? You could also try checking Drafts and Outbox sections of your Gmail account.

Comment: I don't have it in any of my folders (Dratf, Sent, Trash..). I don't have Outbox folder.

Comment: I have the outbox folder in my phone app. Usually when I send an email from my phone, first go to the outbox, and then to sent. If it is not in any folder, maybe it was not sent.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome won't store your email, but only the address that you used gmail.. check your drafts, even you didn't sent it, it will be saved there, if you have sent it, then it must be in sent or outbox folder..

Comment: I don't have it in any of my folders (Dratf, Sent, Trash..). I don't have Outbox folder.

Comment: Then it probably wasn't sent.. but if it wasn't sent , then it must have been saved in the draft folder as gmail successively save your email while editing one. Even if there is none in draft folder, and it is not sent, maybe there was some network down problem, it couldn't save it in draft neither send it..possible..

Answer (score 0):

The content of a page is not stored in the history, so the news is not good: you can see some meta information of the actions you took in gmail, but the content of sent emails is not in the browser history.

Also, consider asking the person you think you sent it to if they have a copy which they can send back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I too find myself in the same situation. Recipient of an scheduled gmail sent and replied to it except I can not find the original and the reply in Sent, draft, etc. However I do see recipient's gmails from previous communications.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).